# Polynomials and matrices space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B=(E_{11},E_{12},E_{21},E_{22})$ be the standard basis of $\operatorname{Mat}_{2,2}(\Bbb R)$ and $B'=(1,x,x^2)$ be the standard basis of $\operatorname{Pol}_2(\Bbb R^2)$. Determine the matrix $M_{B'\rightarrow B}(f)$ of the following function

$$f:\operatorname{Pol}_2(\Bbb R)\rightarrow \operatorname{Mat}_{2,2}(\Bbb R)$$
$$p(x) \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}p'(1)&2p(0)\\0&p''(3)\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm not quite sure how this would work out. Can someone give me a quick explanation? A small example would be really nice and appreciated!!!

Comment: Compute $f(1), f(x)$ and $f(x^2)$, then your matrix will be $\mathcal M(f)=\begin{pmatrix}f(1)&f(x)&f(x^2)\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Surb Then $f(1)$ would simply be $E_{11}$, then im not quite sure what x and $x^2$ would be ....Tahts why im a bit confused because x is a variable

Comment: $f(x)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $f(x)=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Im sorry but why?

Comment: For example, if $p(x)=x$, then $p'(x)=1$ and $p''(x)=0$...

Comment: ah i thought that would be the matrix for f? I think i missunderstood something here. I thought i needed a matrix for f, but i only need one for p?

Comment: No, you need the matrix for $f$ not for $p$...

Comment: For one of my previous comment, there is a mistake : $f(x^2)=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$...

Comment: So $f: p(x) \mapsto Mat_{2,2}$

Comment: Ehm im more confused

Comment: Ouh wait i think i got it, So in the end we have $f(1)=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $f(x)=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and$f(x^2)=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ And this is the $M(f)
$ already?

Comment: So in the end we get $$M(f)=(\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
,\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix})?$$

Comment: It should rather be $$\mathcal M(f)=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&2\\2&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}.$$ (your $f(1)$ is wrong)

Comment: Oh yeah right Thank you so much, please write something as answer, ill mark your answer as the most helpful....PS: i just went over the change of basis matrix in linear algebra, and now it changes a little bit, im lost again....what a shame.......but princible is the same!!